# Linux command-line graphics

Tags: linux, graphics, installation, debian, command-line-interface

I'm need some help. I'd like to write a CLI program, that uses "windows". I mean it looks like the installer of Debian. So I want to know, what C libs I need to do this: http://iomem.com/uploads/tutorial/debiansargeraid/pic002.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing used in debian installer is most probably the [dialog(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_%28software%29) utility. See examples at http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/12/linux-dialog-utility-short-tutorial.html

If you really want C library than what you want is either ncurses library (more low-level) or dialog.h provided with dialog utility.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Ncurses](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) ... it's what debians installer and
most other CLI "windowing" tools use.